# Google indexing to a staging server

Tags: indexing, staging

A site that I was working is resolving to a staging server through google.  I've removed all the information.  How long does it take for google to update the information so that it does not show up. is there anyone that I can contact to move this along?

Answer (score 1):

I also found that google has an expedited process: check it out here

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Answer (score 0):

If the site is down, it will be removed from Google's index automatically.

There is nothing you can do to affect the process besides taking your site down. Expect to see changes in the search results anywhere from a few days to a week or two.

You should not have had the site public, with inbound links, without using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to prevent indexing.

Comment: thanks for the help.  robots.txt will be my best friend from now on.